# How can I implement AMP in angular/ionic website?

Tags: angularjs, performance, mobile, ionic-framework, amp-html

Recently i've heard about the Accelerated Mobile Pages project, and read some info about it.

I wonder how to implement it for existing website that is built upon Ionic and Angular?

Comment: I suggest you do some more reading. AMP pretty much excludes all javascript except its own.

Comment: @KobiCohen, did you find any solution or we cannot just have Angular while planning to have AMP HTML?

Comment: Short answer: no...

Answer (score 6):

Basically there is no nearly possible solution to do that. If you check the doc [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/technical_overview.html#keep-all-third-party-javascript-out-of-the-critical-path).

> ## Keep all third-party JavaScript out of the critical path
>
> Third-party JS likes to use synchronous JS loading. They also like to document.write more sync scripts. For example, If you five ads, and each does three sync loads, with a 1 second latency connection, you’re in 18 seconds of load time just for JS loading.
>
> AMP pages allow third-party JavaScript but only in sandboxed iframes. By banning them into iframes, they can’t block execution of the main page. Even if they trigger multiple style re-calculations, their tiny iframes have very little DOM.
>
> Style-recalculations and layouts are typical to DOM size, so the iframe recalculations are very fast compared to a recalculating styles and layout for the page.

Comment: I actually read the exact same lines, this is why I was asking if somebody already figure out a way to load angular async and bootstrap it later

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this yet with an Angular app but this is what I got from my research to make it happen.

you may consider checking:

- a static site generator for Angular like [scully](https://scully.io/)
- [scully-plugin-amp-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scully-plugin-amp-css)
- [This medium article](https://medium.com/@javier_donoso/https-medium-com-ampgular-angular-to-amp-madrid-day-spa-com-use-case-56d6809604fd)

I'm still searching for a better and fast solution, and I'll try it myself and update my answer.

Note: on [AMP.dev Docs](https://amp.dev/documentation/) they mentioned you can turn any React app to AMP, but I can't find anything regarding Angular on the official AMP docs.