# Convert Angular Webpage in AMP (Accelerated mobile Pages)

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, google-news

I have progressive web app in angular8. Is it possible to convert any created component into AMP? Searched a lot but nowhere related concept is documented well. Please help.

Comment: have you found anything yet bro??

Comment: no bro, i have not got anything regarding angular to amp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I implement AMP in angular/ionic website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35582471/how-can-i-implement-amp-in-angular-ionic-website)